# What is the expected behavior when setting `security.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri` in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

In spring boot, upon configuring a [Resource server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html#boot-features-security-oauth2-resource-server) we have the option to set the `security.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri` property if the access tokens will be JWTs and the issuer provides an endpoint for clients to acquire the public RSA key for verification in JWK format.

What is the expected behavior to initiate a keystore from this JWK? The property is being loaded in the `ResourceServerProperties.JWK` but then what. Should spring boot call this URI and fetch the jwks then create a store for me to use in verification?

I am following this tutorial to setup the configuration of the keystore http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt

```
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("public.txt");
        String publicKey = null;
        try {
            publicKey = IOUtils.toString(resource.getInputStream());
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
        return converter;
    }
```

But instead of loading a `.pem` public key I think I want to load it from a `jwk`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use JWKS, use `JwkTokenStore` in place of `JwtTokenStore`.

[spring-security-oauth2/jwk](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/jwk) internally implements key loading and management according to the [auth0 spec](https://auth0.com/docs/jwks)

You can also see docs on auto-configuration of the same, however i feel configuring it in quite straight-forward (see below).

We don't have to do any verification as [JwkTokenStore](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/jwk/JwkTokenStore.java) sets up the verification with [JwkDefinitionSource](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/jwk/JwkDefinitionSource.java)  [JwkVerifyingJwtAccessTokenConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/jwk/JwkVerifyingJwtAccessTokenConverter.java) using JWKS exposed at `@Value("{jsecurity.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri}")`

However, the [spring-security-oauth2/jwk](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/jwk) classes from spring don't have any public constructors, we often need and can perform any custom steps in AccessTokenConversion, like a common need is to extract jwt content to auth context, we can always inject a custom converter to  [JwkTokenStore](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/jwk/JwkTokenStore.java)

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.jwk.*;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.*
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.*;
import java.utl.*;

@Configuration
class JwtConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices(final TokenStore tokenStore) {
    final DefaultTokenServices dts = new DefaultTokenServices();
    dts.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
    dts.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
    return dts;
  }

  @Bean
  public TokenStore tokenStore( 
    @Value("{jsecurity.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri}") final String jwksUrl,
    final JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter) {
    return new  JwkTokenStore(jwksUrl, jwtAccessTokenConverter, null);
  }

  @Bean
  public JwtAccessTokenConverter createJwtAccessTokenConverter() {
    final JwtAccessTokenConverter converter;   
    converter.setAccessTokenConverter(new  DefaultAccessTokenConverter() {
      @Override
      public OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map) {
        final OAuth2Authentication auth = super.extractAuthentication(map);
        auth.setDetails(map); //this will get spring to copy JWT content into 
        return auth;
        }

      }
    return conveter;
  }
```

---

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  private String resourceId;
  private TokenStore tokenStore;

  public ResourceServerConfig(
    @Value("\${jwt.reourceId}") private String resourceId,
    private TokenStore tokenStore) {
           this.resourceId = resourceId;
           this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
  }

  /**
  * Ensures request to all endpoints ore a
  @Override 
  public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) {
    http.csrf().disable()
     .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
  }

  /**
  * Configure resources
  * Spring OAuth expects "aud" claim in JWT token. That claim's value should match to the resourceId value
  * (if not specified it defaults to "oauth2-resource").
  */
   @Override 
   public void configure(final ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
     resources.resourceId(resourceId).tokenStore(tokenStore);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The main goal of this implementation would be to verify a JWT locally using the corresponding JWK(JSON WEB TOKEN KEY SET). The JWK used for verification is matched using the kid header parameter of the JWT and the kid attribute of the JWK.

The server can validate this token locally without making any network requests, talking to a database, etc. This can potentially make session management faster because instead of needing to load the user from a database (or cache) on every request, you just need to run a small bit of local code. This is probably the single biggest reason people like using JWTs: they are stateless.